# Checker-like Glitch on Cycles and Snow-like Glitch on Eevee Render

Tags: rendering, cycles-render-engine, 3d-view, eevee-render-engine

I'm on blender 2.83.5  Today I tried to render my model here, it seems okay with no problems in render viewport

[image: Render Viewport preview]

And then weird glitch appears as soon as I press F12 .. I did try to render on both render engines

[image: Render on Cycles]
Cycles Render - Checker like texture

[image: Render on EEVEE]
EEVEE render - Snow like texture

So what is the cause of this glitch and how do I solve it? Thank you!

EDIT: the texture is painted manually on Texture Paint workspace. I've already unwrapped all the mesh

Comment: Hello :). Perhaps you have a second copy of your mesh right under it. And if it's set to render only, it doesn't make problems in viewport :).

Comment: Jachym Michal  it worked! thank you!

Comment: No problem, this is actually quite a common issue :). Good luck with your project.

Comment: @JachymMichal How did you know? That's like God level luck or highly impressive knowledge.

Comment: @AlexSandoval You're too kind :). The 'checkered' mesh (called z-fighting) is a typical consequence of overlapping faces :). But 'God level luck' does have a nice ring to it...

Answer (score 1):

Solved by Jachym Michal, there's a backup collection hidden from viewport, but it was set to appear on render

Answer (score 0):

Have you UV unwrapped it yet?  If not you can go into edit mode and start creating seems where to create your flow and use smart unwrap

Comment: I already unwrapped it right away after modelling. The texture is a texture painting